# Editing pubspec.yaml being so slow

Tags: flutter, android-studio, pubspec

Every time I open and edit something in `pubspec.yaml` for my flutter project, my Android Studio is slow, I cannot even click anything in Android Studio, sometimes it needs to restart and sometimes Android Studio needs to end from Task Manager.
It happen always as I start typing anything in pubspec.yaml.

This is the memory usage of pubspec.yaml
[image]

I didn't event run `pub get`, `pub update`.
How can I fix it?

**Edit:**
I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

Comment: In my case, AndroidStudio stops and the indicator spins a couple of mins (or never finishes). My com is Macbook(M1 Pro). So it is very hesitating me to edit pubspec file.

Comment: I have similiar issue. Just found this link searching on Google.
I have 32GB of RAM so I can (slowly) close that tab.
Do you have the plugin "Flutter pub version checker"? Just curious. I've disabled this plugin and seems the problem went away. I want to test for more hours.

Comment: @Scognito, it works,  you should convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: @StevenSann so you disabled "Flutter pub version checker" and worked to you too?
I'm using Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1

Comment: @Scognito, yes, I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1, and this solution work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed disabling the plugin "pub version checker"

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm that by uninstalling plugin **pub checker** did remove the 'lag' on pubspech.yaml file.

You can delete it by going to preferences as shown on image below.

Thanks for the answer guys !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading "Flutter Pub Version Checker", from 1.3.3 to 1.3.5 fixed this for me